# Subgroups of $S_n$, contained in $A_n$ or half of elements are odd permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-homomorphism

good morning. I am unable to resolve this issue, could someone help me, please?

Question: If $H$ is a non-trivial subgroup of $S_{n}$, then or $H \subset A_{n}$ or exacly half of the elements are odd permutations.

Comment: Consider $H\cap A_n$ and $HA_n$. Then use the Second Isomorphism Theorem.

Comment: Tanks, brow. Good Morning. I Uderstand.

Comment: It's the afternoon where I am.

Comment: apply the sign function homomorphism, $\phi$, to $H$ and let $H':= \ker \phi$.  Now apply Lagrange's Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can still reason like this. If $A=A_n\cap H$ and $x\in H\setminus A_n$, then $H=A\cup xA$ and $|A|=|xA|$.
Why does $H=A\cup xA$? If $h\in H$ and $h\notin A$, then $x^{-1}h\in A$. So $h\in xA$.